# Set href id inside content placeholder

Tags: javascript, c#, html, href

I am having a content placeholder inside which i have a table. I have put a href link inside one of the table cells and i want to set its .onclick function in the separate javascript file. I am referencing the href link by ID. Problem is when i assign an ID to hyper link like this:

```
   HyperLink hl = new HyperLink()
   {
     Text = tableCell.Text,
     ID = "hl_id",
   };
   tableCell.Controls.Add(hl);
   tableRow.Controls.Add(tableCell);
```

the ID is not set to "hl_id" but to "contentplaceholderid_hl_id" (found out by inspecting resulting HTML in firefox).
"contentplaceholderid" is the id of the placeholder in which i have the table. 
I have written the javascript function to a "contentplaceholderid_hl_id" element and it works fine. I just want to know why is it appending contentplaceholder id to my href id.

Comment: What is your question? Is it what you subject says? or explaination says?

Comment: the question is how to set href id inside placeholder without placeholder id being appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set ClientIDMode to "static", then the ID will display clientside as it is written.